# Is this possible to check all value in swift array is true instead of looping one by one?

Tags: arrays, swift

I just whether is this possible to have an array of object `MyObject`, and the `MyObject` got a variable called `isTrue`, except from looping the whole array to check whether all the object in that array is true, is that any short hands to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

edit/update: **Swift 4.2 or later**

Swift 4.2 introduced a new method called [`allSatisfy(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy)

```
let bools = [true,false,true,true]

if bools.allSatisfy({$0}) {
    print("all true")
} else {
    print("contains false") // "contains false\n"
}
```

**Swift 5.2** we can also use a KeyPath property

```
class Object {
    let isTrue: Bool
    init(_ isTrue: Bool) {
        self.isTrue = isTrue
    }
}

let obj1 = Object(true)
let obj2 = Object(false)
let obj3 = Object(true)

let objects = [obj1,obj2,obj3]

if objects.allSatisfy(\.isTrue) {
    print("all true")
} else {
    print("not all true")  // "not all true\n"
}
```

---

Comment: boolArray is storing an object instead of pure boolean value.

Comment: Do you know if theres a difference in performance between this and using for loop ?

Comment: Keep in mind though, allSatisfy in empty array returns true :)

Comment: Well that’s expected behavior since there is no elements. The same would happen if you check it the collection not contains false

Answer (score 31):

As of **Xcode 10** and **Swift 4.2**  you can now use [`allSatisfy(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy) with a predicate:

```
let conditions = [true, true, true]
if conditions.allSatisfy({$0}) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A purely functional way using `reduce` function:

```
let boolArray = [true,true,true,true]
let isAllTrue = boolArray.reduce(true, combine: {$0 && $1}) // true
```

Comment: Keep in mind: this doesn't short circuit. A false could be found on the first item, but it'll proceed to go through the whole list anyway.

Comment: That's correct, thanks for pointing that out. Use on significantly large arrays is therefore discouraged.

Comment: Is there a way to do this functionally and still short circuit?  This strikes me as a better approach than the selected answer because it's more generalizable (i.e. what if you want to check if all values equal `2`?)

Comment: @Kevin: to short circuit you could try `let isAllTrue = boolArray.index(where: { $0 == false }) == nil`.  However note that this would return `true` for an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do it is using a predicate:

```
let notAllTrue = contains(array) {
    item in item.isTrue == false
}
```

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: less didactic, but more programmer friendly (but still too many !s)

Comment: You can use an implicit arg too `{!$0.isTrue}`

Answer (score 2):

Try any of these.

```html
1.

    let names = ["Sofia", "Camilla", "Martina", "Mateo", "Nicolás"]

    if names.allSatisfy({ $0.count >= 5 }){
        print("true")
    }else{
        print("false")
    }
```

```html
2.

        class SelectedModel {
            var isSelected : Bool = false
            required init(_ isSelected: Bool) {
                self.isSelected = isSelected
            }
        }
        let model1 = SelectedModel(true)
        let model2 = SelectedModel(true)
        let model3 = SelectedModel(true)
        let modelArr = [model1,model2,model3]

        if modelArr.allSatisfy({ $0.isSelected == true }){
             print("true")
        }else{
             print("false")
        }
```

Comment: `== true` is redundant `if modelArr.allSatisfy( { $0.isSelected } )`

Comment: Swift 5.2 `allSatisfy(\.isSelected)`